# Аналог TitledBorder

Tags: gwt, java

Если я пишу приложение, используя Swing, то с помощью `TitledBorder` могу сделать такую панель:

```
panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Border Title"));
```

[image]

Есть ли возможность сделать что-то подобное в GWT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это же [`CaptionPanel`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/CaptionPanel.html).

Пример [тут](http://examples.roughian.com/index.htm#Panels~CaptionPanel).